# Javascript not working in XAMPP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I run my javascript code in html it's fine, but when I run the same code on localhost it shows me this message in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

This is my code

```
<form method="post">
    <ul id="edit">
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="adress" id="adress" placeholder="Adresa" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Grad" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="number" name="zip" id="zip" placeholder="Poštanski broj" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="tel" name="phone_number" id="phone_number" placeholder="Tel. broj" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Lozinka" />
            <div class="password_strength" id="password_strength"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="password" name="repassword" id="repassword" placeholder="Ponoviti lozinku" onkeyup="checkPass(); return false;" />
        </li><div id="confirmMessage"></div>
        <br>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Izmjeni" />
        </li>
        <br>
    </ul>
</form>

<script>
    function checkPass() {
        var password = document.getElementById('password');
        var repassword = document.getElementById('repassword');
        var message = document.getElementById('confirmMessage');
        var goodColor = "#66cc66";
        var badColor = "#ff6666";
        if (password.value == repassword.value) {
            repassword.style.backgroundColor = goodColor;
            message.style.color = goodColor;
            message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
        } else {
            repassword.style.backgroundColor = badColor;
            message.style.color = badColor;
            message.innerHTML = "Passwords Do Not Match!";
        }
    }

    $('#password, #username').keydown(function (e) {
        if (e.which == 32) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    $('#password').keyup(function () {
        var PasswordLength = $(this).val().length;
        var PasswordStrength = $('#password_strength');

        if (PasswordLength <= 0) {
            PasswordStrength.html('');
            PasswordStrength.removeClass('normal weak strong verystrong');
        }
        if (PasswordLength > 0 && PasswordLength < 4) {
            PasswordStrength.html('weak');
            PasswordStrength.removeClass('normal strong verystrong').addClass('weak');
        }
        if (PasswordLength > 4 && PasswordLength < 8) {
            PasswordStrength.html('Normal');
            PasswordStrength.removeClass('weak strong verystrong').addClass('normal');
        }
        if (PasswordLength >= 8 && PasswordLength < 12) {
            PasswordStrength.html('Strong');
            PasswordStrength.removeClass('weak normal verystrong').addClass('strong');
        }
        if (PasswordLength >= 12) {
            PasswordStrength.html('Very Strong');
            PasswordStrength.removeClass('weak normal strong').addClass('verystrong');
        }
    });

</script>
```

First part of the code should add color to my input box for repeaedt password in green if password match or red if they don't, but it is always red.

Second part should add a class for password strength, but nothing.

Comment: where is `confirmMessage`?

Comment: @HardyMathew I edited post

Comment: Can you add your code on jsfiddle so we can take a look?

Comment: @BaconJuice in JS fiddle it works, but it doesn't work on my localhost

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,

I made mistake in part of code what I didn't post in my question.
I had two same password ids.

So I had to replace:

```
<form action="login.php">
    E-mail: <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail"/><br><br>
    Lozinka: <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Prijavi se"/><br><br>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; float:right;">Zaboravljena lozinka?</a>
</form>
```

With:

```
<form action="login.php">
    E-mail: <input type="mail" name="mail" id="mail"/><br><br>
    Lozinka: <input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Prijavi se"/><br><br>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; float:right;">Zaboravljena lozinka?</a>
</form>
```

Thank you all for help :)

Answer (score 0):

First you should have a line number associated with your error code if you used the console.  Second I noticed that there is a  line that ends with no semi-colon

```
message.innerHTML = "Passwords Match!"
```

which is not an automatic error, but you want to eliminate possible misinterpretation by your browser.